# How to get male/female split for particular household income range in the United States

Tags: usa, us-census, income

Where is the best resource to get the most recent Male / Female split of household incomes above $80K+ (or similar) in the United States?

[This U.S. Census table](https://www.census.gov/quickfacts/fact/table/US/INC110218#INC110218) has "Female persons, percent" but I'm not able to filter by household income, which is what is desired.

Any help or tips appreciated! Seems like a straightforward question, but not sure which Census / government data explorer is most appropriate for this question.

Comment: in addition to the table you link, there are lots of raw datasets. have you had a look? https://www.census.gov/data/datasets.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about split of household incomes, I dont think they produce a table for that. But table B19325 from the Census Bureau's American Community Survey (ACS) has sex by income broken down into ranges. You'd have to us $75,000 + as they don't have it at $80,000+. The top two categories are $75k to $99k and $100k or more.

here is a direct link to the table:
https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=b19325&hidePreview=false&tid=ACSDT1Y2018.B19325

You can also explore the data/tables that the ACS have by reviewing the table shells and table list in the documentation found here: https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/technical-documentation/table-shells.html

There's also a compiled Excel version you can find here http://gisdiva.com/downloads/acs2018-5yr/ that has the tables listed in Appendix A and the the table shells as Appendix C.

if that still doesn't get you what you are looking for, you can play around with the ACS  microdata at iPUMS.org here https://usa.ipums.org/usa/sda/